# Selenium scripts are running very slow when connected to VPN

Tags: selenium, networking, selenium-webdriver, vpn

I have written selenium scripts for my project and when started running them they run very slowly. It is so long time to perform each action. Have given my scripts to one of my colleague who is working from onshore where they do not need a VPN.

Can anyone please tell me what to do or if I can get some work around that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently in the same position.

> started running they run very slowly

The actual problem comes from the client's (browser) send and received data across your test environment. The simplest solution would be - if you have any devops admin that can [whitelist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist) your PC, so you could get a free access. Never the less this could be a security issue.

Comment: I think you are right, have complained about this to my system administrator. Hopefully, I don't get such issues again.